# What's the best practices on UItabBars in navigationControllers?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating an app using UItabBarController.  I have 5 tabBar items at the bottom.
should I wrap navigationController in each item?  Is that the best practice, and if not what's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The tabs in a `UITabBarController` represent independent sections within an app. An example is Apple's Clock app. It has 4 tabs which are completely independent of each other.

A navigation controller represents a top-down hierarchy / stack of view controllers (meaning you start with a root view controller and then 'push' view controllers onto the stack. This almost inevitably means that it shows a 'logical flow'. You perform an action like selecting something on a view controller, which takes you into a more detailed view related to the action you performed. An example is Apple's Notes app which shows a list of folders of notes, selecting a folder pushes the screen with the list of notes in that folder onto the navigation stack, selecting a note in that list pushes the note that the user tapped on, onto the top of the list of notes.

Generally you should have tab bar controller as your app's root view controller and then each of the tabs could have a navigation controller as its root. It wouldn't usually have a tab-bar inside a navigation controller.

One case where a tab-bar could live inside a navigation controller is when a tabbed interface is presented modally.

To your question "should I wrap navigationController in each item", I think yes each tab should have a navigation controller as the root if a navigation hierarchy is required in that tab.

Hope this helps you.